# Connecting to remote tty using perl

Tags: perl, testing, automation, serial-port, tty

i am developing a test automation host which is currently connected to 10 embedded controllers via serial ports (/dev/ttyS*)

to speed up the testing i wish to add more host and enable them to also talk to the controllers. However the controller must remain connected to the first host.

the entire test automation software is written in perl so i am looking for a perl based solution. i am currently using Device::SerialPort to talk to the controllers. until now it did the work just fine

is there a way using Device::SerialPort to connect to tty devices on a remote machine
if not is there a similar perl module which can do that

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to the remote host via SSH, you can also get your Perl script to run on the remote host. Maybe as a daemon. Then each script talks to the devices via local ttys, and they could talk to each other over TCP or UDP sockets, using a protocol you define.

Answer (score 0):

Found it !

From a different forum i found a small application call "socat".

it passes all tty communication through a socket.
on the host side you use socat to create a socket and on the client side you create a psuedo tty (pty) which emulates the remote tty through the socket.